# separate a large 7GB tab limited file into multiple files

Tags: awk

I want to separate a large 7GB file into multiple files (each file size= 1 GB) without changing it's format.. How is it possible ? AWK or any script is available? My file look like this:

```
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCA_001188035.1_1       100.00  159     0       0       1       159     1       159     8e-113   324
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCF_000878595.1_1595    100.00  159     0       0       1       159     853     1011    2e-104   327
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCA_001267965.1_78      100.00  159     0       0       1       159     853     1011    2e-104   327
GCA_001188035.1_1       GCF_000568495.1_4683    100.00  159     0       0       1       159     853     1011    2e-104   327
GCA_001188035.1_2       GCF_000568495.1_4684    100.00  137     0       0       1       137     1       137     8e-97    281
GCA_001188035.1_2       GCA_001188035.1_2       100.00  137     0       0       1       137     1       137     8e-97    281
GCA_001188035.1_2       GCF_000878595.1_1594    98.54   137     2       0       1       137     1       137     5e-96    280
```

Answer (score 0):

`man split`

If you know the number of lines (thanks to [wc -l](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)) it is quite easy to calculte the argument to pass to `split -l`

Comment: @user3295716 if so, you may consider [accepting this answer](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)